# Turning an autocorrelation formula into code?

Tags: calculus

I am a programmer and my current project requires me to turn a research paper into runnable code.

My level of math experience is fairly low, but what needs to be done has to be done either way, and I'm determined to learn new things.

The research paper can be found here: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/0124/09d447691fd74c49bc407b3818b4617641b2.pdf

On page 2 we can see two formulas, one (the first one):

[image]

of which I think I have correctly programmed as it is giving me the following results:

[image]

which has similarities to Fig 1a:
[image]

However I can not figure out how to get results to resemble Fig 1b and 1c.

Would it be too much to ask for someone to explain what's going on with the second formula on page 2, or even pseudo-code that would reflect the formula?

If it is too much to ask for, I'd like to start by asking:
What is this part of the formula doing? Is it multiplying `s[n]` and `s[n + l]` which would result in `s[n] * s[n + l]`?

More about this as a code code can be found in the following StackOverflow question that I made, which is more code-oriented: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51352890/is-this-autocorrelation-formula-correctly-programmed?noredirect=1#comment89739564_51352890

Answer (score 0):

First, this is my understanding of skimming the reseach paper. It may not be correct or even 'near the spot'.

Fig 1a) is *not* showing the application of any of the formulas, it is showing the input sample (called $s[n]$ in he formulas). That's written in the part below the figure, where it shortly explains what (a), (b) and (c) are. If you have applied forumla (1), you should have gotten something curve 1b).

Also, formulas (1) and (2) are using a letter "l" (el) for the lag, not (as one would assume from a casual inspection) the number "1" (one).

You are correct that both formulas are summing up a bunch of products of the form $s[n]\times s[n+l]$. They both start that summation at $n=i$ ($i$ seems to be zero in the examples). They differ in how far they sum, formula (1) sums until $n=i+N-l$, while formula (2) sums until $n=i+N-2l$.

The paper says

> Figure   1b-c   show   the   ACF   of   the   acoustic waveform
>   which   were   normalized   and   half-wave rectified  from  Fig.  1a.

I understand what normalized means (it means that the value for $R_X(l)$ has been divided by $R_X(0)$, such that the curves in 1b) and 1c) start with a value of 1 at $l=0$. I have no idea what "half-wave rectified" means, though.

Comment: careful with the second equation, it actually sums until `n = i + N - l - 1` theres an "el" and a "one" in there.
and you are correct, I should've gotten something like fig b, but I'm not, surely my code is wrong somewhere. hmmm....

Comment: Can you post the code? I meas once you understand what the summation does, it should be 2-3 lines of code (for the forumula).
About  "el" vs. one: I only realized just now that you can copy the text from the pdf and see what is actually used. OTOH, then I don't understand the big difference between 1b) and 1c): Leaving out one summand should not influence the result that much.

Comment: I've included a link to my code in the question.

Comment: I've included a link to my code in the question.

Comment: I can't comment on the coding things at the moment, but the most important thing I see is that lag is always set to 1. This is not what it is supposed to be. The figures you see in 1b) and 1c) are figures where the lag is the **independent variable**. In the formula for $R_x$ all things are 'given': The input data s[n], the frame size $N$ etc. The only thing that can be varied by you is the lag. 
See also the sentence from the area between formula (1) and (2): "The lag value that produces maximum peak will be chosen as the pitch period."

Comment: So you should take your function CalcAutocorrelation, and add the lag as a parameter (remove the pulic int Lag first):
public float CalcAutocorrelation(float[] frame, int Lag)
Then calculate that function in a loop for Lag from 1 to N-1

Comment: I was thinking about this as well, but I was not sure exactly how that code would look.
In my current code you can see an already existing loop. So a loop in a loop?
I tried that a few days ago, but the results were messed up. I have to figure it out.

Comment: As I said, the CalcAutocorrelation function stays, gets an additional parameter lag. Then the main program calls it repeatedly, in a loop.

Comment: of course, but every time the main program calls it, it sends a new frame. `N` might be larger or smaller than amount of frames available so `lag` might either not reach `N-1` or it might exceed `N-1`, I highly doubt that your most recent suggestion is the correct implementation. I do however agree that `lag` has to be iterated to `N-1` during the autocorrelation calculation... somewhere...

Comment: Whatever the "it" is that the main program calls , that part of the code needs to find out what the frame is, and from that frame the N is determined. Then it loops over lag from 1 to N-1 and calls CalcAutocorrelation(frame, lag). The return values are saved somewhere and the highest (or the high) values are the lag values that are candidates for the pitch.
I think you might need to take care of the half-waeve rectifying of the input first, because currently the input sample contains negative values, which will throw off the autocorellation function, IMO.